# In Odoo 15 reports appear black if i try to use data from table

Tags: python, xml-parsing, odoo-15

I try to make a bigger report with tables and graphics.

As I just started using it I take step by step. :) So I created a addon that will use the data from crm.leads.

The template works if I don't parse data from docs, I I try to use docs it returns:

```
odoo-1   | Traceback (most recent call last):
odoo-1   |   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 2003, in report_download
odoo-1   |     data = dict(url_decode(url.split('?')[1]).items())  # decoding the args represented in JSON
odoo-1   | IndexError: list index out of range
```

At this moment I have the following:

view/xpf_reporting

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <template id="xpf_reporting_template">
        <t t-debug="pdb"/>
        <t t-call="web.html_container">
            <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
                <t t-call="web.external_layout">
                    <div class="page">
                        <div>
                            <h1>REPORT</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <table class="table table-condensed">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Title</th>
                                        <th>Expected return date</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <span t-field="o.user_id"/>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <span t-field="o.expected_revenue"/>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </t>
            </t>
        </t>
    </template>
</odoo>
```

and the views/xpf_reporting.xml

```
<record id="action_print_report" model="ir.actions.report">
    <field name="name">XPF PDF report</field>
    <field name="model">crm.lead</field>
    <field name="report_type">qweb-html</field>
    <field name="report_name">xpf_reporting.xpf_reporting_template</field>
    <field name="binding_model_id" ref="model_crm_lead"/>
    <field name="binding_type">report</field>
</record>
```

What can I do?